# How to tell ORMLite not to override values in DB with null

Tags: android, sqlite, ormlite

I'm using ORMLite for Android to store data in a SQLite database.

In some cases I receive incomplete information from the WebService and therefore some of my object values are null. ORMLite then tries to store the new object (with the null values) into SQLite database.

What I want to achieve is, that ORMLite shall skip storing properties with null-values, if the local database already has a value for it.

e.g.: I have a local Person object with First Name and Last Name. When I receive new data from WebService which only contains First Name (which means Last Name == null) and I call `personDAO.udpate(receivedPersonObject)`, the Last Name in database will be overwritten with null.

**Is there a way to stop ORMLite from writing null-values to database when using `update()` method?**

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a way to stop ORMLite from writing null-values to database when using update() method?

No.  You can mark the field with `canBeNull = false` but that will just throw an exception if it tries to update with `null`.  I think that you are going to have to either check the values to see if there are null values or use the `UpdateBuilder` and only update the particular fields that you need to update.

```
UpdateBuilder<Foo,Integer> updateBuilder = new UpdateBuilder<Foo,Integer>();
updateBuilder.where().eq(Foo.ID_FIELD, foo.getId());
if (foo.getFirstName() != null) {
   updateBuilder.where().eq(Foo.FIRST_NAME_FIELD, foo.getFirstName());
}
if (foo.getLastName() != null) {
   updateBuilder.where().eq(Foo.LAST_NAME_FIELD, foo.getLastName());
}
...
updateBuilder.update();
```

Answer (score 1):

One other way you can approach this is:

1. Get the existing object from database with specific id.
2. Update the properties of the object retrieved from the database to the ones passed in, checking for null values and other business rules.
3. Persist the updated object back into database.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should check for null values yourself before calling the `update()` method

Comment: I already know that some of the properties of the object are null. How to continue then?

Comment: So you still want to update the non-null values of the object stored in database ? Then you can query the object from the database, replace the null values in the object that has been recieved from WebService with the ones from the object in database, then call the `update()` method. I can't think of anything else right now